# smallest size selenium-java.jar

Tags: selenium, jar

I have built an runnable jar using selenium.What my jar does is it just opens a browser(InternetExplorer) and does some basic tasks like form submitting. The problem is with the size of the jar. My application jar size is 6.5 mb. The selenium java jar which is included in my application has taken most of the size(3.5mb).

I have searched for the smallest size selenium java jar. but failed. 
Could someone help me or show me the way to solve my problem